# Scroll by x-axis

Tags: html, css

How forcibly add scroll to the bottom (x-axis) of the div that all squares would go to the right?

CSS:

```css
#videowall-grid{
    width:700px; 
    border:1px dotted #dddddd;
    display: none; 
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align:center;
}

#videowall-grid .videowall-row{
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 700px;
    height: 120px;
}

#videowall-grid .videowall-square{
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px dashed #dddddd;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}​
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="videowall-grid" style="display: block;">
    <div class="videowall-row">
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_1">afasfasdfas</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_1">afasfasdfas</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_1">afasfasdfas</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_1">afasfasdfas</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_1">afasfasdfas</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_1">afasfasdfas</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_1">afasfasdfas</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_2">sadfasfasdafsdasdfsafsadfsafsfadfasdfasfasdfasf</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_3">adfasfdasdf channel 1 camera with a very very very</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_4">asdfadsffasdsf</div>
    </div>
    <div class="videowall-row">
        <div id="2_1" class="videowall-square">asdfasd cam1</div>
        <div id="2_2" class="videowall-square">asdfasd cam2</div>
        <div id="2_3" class="videowall-square">asdfasd cam4</div>
        <div id="2_4" class="videowall-square">button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="videowall-row">
        <div id="3_1" class="videowall-square"></div>
        <div id="3_2" class="videowall-square">button</div>
        <div id="3_3" class="videowall-square">button</div>
        <div id="3_4" class="videowall-square">button</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Could you create a JSfiddle for this.. thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow-x:scroll` to **#videowall-grid**?

Comment: @KentPawar http://jsfiddle.net/nonamez/zPL3K/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add [`overflow: auto;`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html) to the squares so that overflowing text stays inside.
- Add [`white-space: nowrap;`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html) on the rows to force the squares to be on the same row.
- You can set the line height equal to the square's height `line-height: 100px;` **or** you could set a padding equal to the height (100/2 = 50) `padding: 50px 0;` to make the text vertically centered <sup>(Edit after comment)</sup>

[Vertical center with line-height](http://jsfiddle.net/qLy2j/).
[Vertical center with padding](http://jsfiddle.net/H5tND/).

---

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/T3rrA/) | Code

CSS

```css
#videowall-grid{
    width:700px;
    border:1px dotted #dddddd;
    display: none;
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align:center;
}

#videowall-grid .videowall-row{
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 700px;
    height: 120px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#videowall-grid .videowall-square{
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px dashed #dddddd;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div id="videowall-grid" style="display: block;">
    <div class="videowall-row">
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_1">afasfasdfas</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_1">afasfasdfas</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_1">afasfasdfas</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_1">afasfasdfas</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_1">afasfasdfas</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_1">afasfasdfas</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_1">afasfasdfas</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_2">sadfasfasdafsdasdfsafsadfsafsfadfasdfasfasdfasf</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_3">adfasfdasdf channel 1 camera with a very very very</div>
        <div class="videowall-square" id="1_4">asdfadsffasdsf</div>
    </div>
    <div class="videowall-row">
        <div id="2_1" class="videowall-square">asdfasd cam1</div>
        <div id="2_2" class="videowall-square">asdfasd cam2</div>
        <div id="2_3" class="videowall-square">asdfasd cam4</div>
        <div id="2_4" class="videowall-square">button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="videowall-row">
        <div id="3_1" class="videowall-square"></div>
        <div id="3_2" class="videowall-square">button</div>
        <div id="3_3" class="videowall-square">button</div>
        <div id="3_4" class="videowall-square">button</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but may be you have also some tip on how to set middle position of the text in square?

Comment: @Kirix Updated the answer. Links with examples added. :)

Comment: but if there is some button or text? May be is some universal method?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like who want a JS solution. But have you considered using http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Would make things a lot easier.